# Remove axis from animation.ArtistAnimation python

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, imshow

Here is a  screenshot from an animations I have created  in python:

[image]

I would like to remove the second axis that is being created. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
%matplotlib notebook

steps = np.arange(0,t_steps,5)
img = []
for k in steps:
    img.append(mpimg.imread(r'C:\Users\nikos.000\MHD1D\figures\jpg\test\_test%d.jpg'% k) ) #path file
                         
frames = [] # for storing the generated images
fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(len(img)):
    frames.append([plt.imshow(img[i], cmap=cm.Greys_r,animated=True, aspect='auto')])

ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, frames, interval=50, blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=1000)
# ani.save('movie.mp4')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    fig = plt.figure("Animation")

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

    #append logic to ims

    ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims)
```

This should do the task.

If you want to remove the bounding box too. Use:

```
    ax.axis('off')
```